# How to Load Different Images On Table View Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two views in 1st view say A for save an image in document directory on save button click and then second view say B. I have two upload that image with specific cell of the table.In below code i am trying to compare the image with specific user email id.Email is common in both views. So can i differentiate the specific user with their email and on their table view cell we show their images differently. But i am not able to do that... How can this to be achieved in Ios? AnyOne can help me out for this....My Code for save and load image in document directory  are
`enter code here`

**View A**

```
-(void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image
{
    if (image != nil)
    {
        NSArray *paths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                              @"iosImage.png" ];
        NSString *fileName = [path stringByAppendingFormat:email];
        NSLog(@"The result of Concatenate String =%@",fileName);
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                  [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"The Path of the directory %@",path);
    }
}
```

**View B**

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
    NSLog(@"Email^^^^^^^^^%@",imgEmail);
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths =        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          @"iosImage.png" ];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@",[fileMgr     contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: are you want to display same images in View B that you already download in document directory?

Comment: Yup.... I want to display same image which i saved on button click ..@None

Comment: i think if you are fetching response then response containe unique user Id and email ?

Comment: have you checked that are you successfully written image in document directory?

Comment: @None...,My loaded images shown.. but in all table view cell they show same image, i want different image for specific user

Comment: @NishaGupta, you can encrypt your emailID and use the same as file name. check http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81630/how-to-load-different-images-on-table-view-cell

you can ask your query there

Comment: @Sujay...I didnt get your point Sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modified `saveImage` and `loadImage` function as per below.

```
-(void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image filePath:(NSString*)fileNameEmail
{
     if (image != nil)
     {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameEmail];

        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
              [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

     }
}

- (UIImage*)loadImage:(NSString*)fileNameEmail
{
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameEmail];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
     return image;
}
```

**Edit** : You can get specific image like below.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.youimageview.image = [self loadImage:[[yourArray indexOfObject:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"youemailkey"]];
    return cell;
}
```

may this help you.

Comment: @ None,...I want to show different iages on table view cell for different users, Ur code does not do that

Comment: it is same as you called earlier just pass one more parameter that is your email..

Comment: you can called like [self saveImage:yourImageObject   filePath:email];

Comment: removed NSLog from saveImage method.

Comment: path variable is not exist.

Comment: first checked that are you successfully able to download image in document directory?

Comment: if downloaded the what is its filename?

Comment: @NishaGupta, i am asking to check my saveImage code. because i have not checked that due to time complexity. if it working fine then ahead you don't face difficulty to display images.

Comment: @NishaGupta, i have successfully donwload images in document directory using my code. can you please once again replace saveImage code.

Comment: Yup.. Now i save the image in document directory with your code. But till now it wont load the image @None

Comment: . i think now i have to compare the image name with email id to show specific image for specific user. but how to compare can u please tell me..@None

Comment: @NishaGupta, you don't need to compare. just passed email address for respective cell. loadImage function will return specific image for that email address.

Comment: I fetched data in table  from json so how i pass image to particular different cell @None

Comment: just like cell.imageView.image = [self loadImage:userEmail];

Comment: By doing this image will be displayed on all table cell. I want it on specific cell @None....

Comment: so write code in cellforRowAtindexPath and passed different userEmail for indivitual user row.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this

Comment: @NishaGupta, check my edit answer. you can assign such way image in UIImageView.

Comment: Sir i have one more question.. How to make Array of images which is saved in document directory. Otherwise your code is very helpful...

Comment: where do you story response of webservice?

Comment: Sir i want to save my image localy and also load image locally ... Image will not to send on webservice

Comment: no, i am taking about. you are received response write. and download image write. so while downloading image, you have response  in array.

Comment: I just save the image in document directory. And load that particular image in table view cell. But i want to load different images on different cells

Comment: give me your response which you received after api called?

Comment: Check The response in Posted answer

Comment: @NishaGupta, do not write response as answer. please update whole response structure in you question.

Comment: @None, you are bit wrong here. email-ID always contain dot(.) so she can't save image file with more then 1 dot(.). so she need to use unique user name

Comment: @Sujay, this is just for reference purpose. she can  used any unique identifier from web serivice response.

Answer (score 1):

If you have saved different image in documents directory but at the time of loading in tableview cell, it is showing one image, then just set image of your imageview to Nil before setting new image like below:

```
cell.imageView.image = Nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the below code we can asynchronously paste image on table view cell.

```
NSString *imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",d.emailId];

UIImage *image = [self loadImage:imageName];  
if (image==nil)
{
    [imgProfilePic setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"userEdit.png"]];
}
else
{
    [imgProfilePic setImage:image];
}
photos =image;

NSLog(@"^^^^^^^^^^^^^^%@",photos);

[cell.contentView addSubview:imgProfilePic];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also  you can use like that,

```
-(NSString *)ImageString{

    NSData *imgdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgView.image, 0.5);
    NSString *imagename =[self generateImageName];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",   DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,imagename]
                         contents:imgdata
                       attributes:nil];
    return imagename;

    }
       -(NSString *)generateImageName{

        int timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSString *StrImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image_%d.png",timestamp];
        NSLog(@"image name=%@",StrImage);
        return StrImage;
    }
```

And Define In Header like that,

```
#define DOCUMENTS_FOLDER [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]
```