# Pop To Next View Controller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 5-6 view controllers. I am trying to pop to  specific view controller.Like i have first view name "Guest" second view name "Vendor" third view name "Address". Now i am in "Address" view i want to go in "Guest" view.  But this will not happened correctly. Anyone can help me out for this. below is the given code which i used to pop from view..

```
- (void)addButtonAction
{
    if([selectVisitor.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Guest"]])
    {
        NSLog(@"NISha");
        for (UIViewController *Controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
        {
            if ([Controller isKindOfClass:[GuestView class]])
            {
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:Controller animated:YES];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why `popToViewController` ?

Comment: After saving some data i want to go in that view where my data is saved thats why i want to pop to that view that is guest

Comment: `popToViewController` will work only when you have that view in your `navigationController` stack.

Comment: you are using wrong approach. Use - `(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //your code
}` instead.

Comment: Then how i come to know  that i have that view in my stack or not???

Comment: i am not using storyboard so i cant use segue. @Lalit

Comment: @NishaGupta, are you using xib?

Comment: How can this be done..Can u please elaborate me

Comment: Yes @Sujay I am using xib. But i do all work programatically not by drag and drop

Comment: check this link, how `popToViewController` works http://adoptioncurve.net/images/2013/04/navigation.png

Comment: Ohkiee @Sujay sir.. Now what i do .. i dnt have that view in stack.. Then how can i goes from adrress view to guest view

Comment: But i am beginner so i called u Sir.. :-)

Comment: @NishaGupta, as you wish

Comment: @NishaGupta: Did you get your answer? Or still this needs to be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)addButtonAction {

    if([selectVisitor.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Guest"]])
    {
        BOOL flag = FALSE;
        for (UIViewController *Controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
        {
            if ([Controller isKindOfClass:[GuestView class]])
            {
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:Controller animated:YES];
                flag = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!flag) {
        GuestView *controllerObject = [[GuestView alloc] initWithNibName:@"GuestViewNibName" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerObject animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: which question? could you plz share your question link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041937/how-to-load-different-images-on-table-view-cell.... Check the link Sir :p

Comment: @MayankJain, how do you know that view controller is already in navigation controller stack ?? 
What if she has not visited to that specific view controller?
**`popToViewController` will work only when you have that view in your `navigationController` stack.**
Check her code and plz read all the other comments first.

Comment: @Sujay you have updated your answer 20 min ago. Now this is right... before this you were trying to push VC everytime.

Comment: @MayankJain, its true, my previous code was pushing `viewController` in `navigationController` stack everytime. but your comment "why are you pushing a view controller which is already in navigation hierarchy ?" was also **not constructive**. By the way lalit's answer is completely wrong because she was trying to pop to specific view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```